# Broken packages when installing Wine

Tags: package-management, wine

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit), but can't install Wine. All I get is broken dependencies.

Tried all in my mind...

```
sudo apt-get update  && upgrade  and even with dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I've checked in the dpkg status file (`/var/lib/dpkg/status/`) after anything broken, but couldn't find anything.

What to do?

Q4wine worked, but not wine?

This happens when I try to install wine:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

[My text is in swedish...]
Basically saying; Dependent on wine1.6

---

When I try to install wine1.6; `sudo apt-get install wine1.6`
...dependent on wine1.6-i386

---

When I try to install wine1.6-386; `sudo apt-get install wine1.6-i386`

---

```
... wine1.6-i386:i386 : Beroende av: libglu1-mesa:i386 men det kommer inte att installeras eller
                                  libglu1:i386
                     Beroende av: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.2) men det kommer inte att installeras
                     Beroende av: libgphoto2-port10:i386 (>= 2.5.2) men det kommer inte att installeras
                     Beroende av: liblcms2-2:i386 (>= 2.2+git20110628) men det kommer inte att installeras
                     Rekommenderar: libsane:i386 men det kommer inte att installeras
```

---

I added support for i386 architecture doing as proposed below, but it did not change or help anything.

But when I tried aptitude instead of apt-get, I got a little longer:

I got a lot of options of fixing the dependencies issues, with a question of y/n/q. But when answered y, it does not start install, only goes back to prompt with info "nothing installed".

---

This is the output I am getting;

> cai@caiThink:~$ sudo aptitude install wine
>
> [sudo] password for cai:
>
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>     fonts-horai-umefont{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libasound2:i386{a} 
>     libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} 
>     libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libcapi20-3{a} 
>     libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcgmanager0:i386{ab} libcups2:i386{a} 
>     libdrm-intel1:i386{a} libdrm-nouveau2:i386{a} libdrm-radeon1:i386{a} 
>     libelf1:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libexpat1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a} 
>     libflac8:i386{a} libfontconfig1:i386{a} libfreetype6:i386{a} 
>     libgcrypt11:i386{a} libgd3:i386{a} libgif4:i386{a} 
>     libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{a} libglapi-mesa:i386{a} 
>     libglib2.0-0:i386{a} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgnutls26:i386{a} 
>     libgpg-error0:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port10:i386{a} 
>     libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} 
>     libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386{a} libgstreamer0.10-0:i386{a} 
>     libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} 
>     libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libice6:i386{a} 
>     libieee1284-3:i386{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} 
>     libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} libjpeg8:i386{a} libk5crypto3:i386{a} 
>     libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} 
>     libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{ab} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} 
>     libllvm3.4:i386{a} libltdl7:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libogg0:i386{a} 
>     libopenal1:i386{a} liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} 
>     libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} 
>     libpciaccess0:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} 
>     libsamplerate0:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} 
>     libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libsm6:i386{a} 
>     libsndfile1:i386{a} libspeexdsp1:i386{a} libsqlite3-0:i386{a} 
>     libssl1.0.0:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{a} libtiff5:i386{a} 
>     libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386{a} libudev1:i386{a} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} 
>     libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libvorbis0a:i386{a} 
>     libvorbisenc2:i386{a} libvpx1:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} 
>     libwrap0:i386{a} libx11-6:i386{a} libx11-xcb1:i386{a} libxau6:i386{a} 
>     libxcb-dri2-0:i386{a} libxcb-dri3-0:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a} 
>     libxcb-present0:i386{a} libxcb-sync1:i386{a} libxcb1:i386{a} 
>     libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a} libxdamage1:i386{a} 
>     libxdmcp6:i386{a} libxext6:i386{a} libxfixes3:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a} 
>     libxinerama1:i386{a} libxml2:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} 
>     libxrender1:i386{a} libxshmfence1:i386{a} libxslt1.1:i386{a} 
>     libxt6:i386{a} libxxf86vm1:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} 
>     p11-kit-modules:i386{a} p7zip{a} unixodbc{a} wine wine-gecko2.21{a} 
>     wine-gecko2.21:i386{a} wine-mono0.0.8{a} wine1.6{a} wine1.6-amd64{a} 
>     wine1.6-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a}
>
> 0 packages upgraded, 126 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 155 MB of archives. After unpacking 546 MB will be used.
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> liblcms2-2 : Breaks: liblcms2-2:i386 (!= 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1) but 2.5-0ubuntu4 is to be installed.
>    liblcms2-2:i386 : Breaks: liblcms2-2 (!= 2.5-0ubuntu4) but 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1 is installed.
>    libcgmanager0 : Breaks: libcgmanager0:i386 (!= 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1) but 0.24-0ubuntu7.5 is to be installed.
>    libcgmanager0:i386 : Breaks: libcgmanager0 (!= 0.24-0ubuntu7.5) but 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 is installed.
>   The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
>       Keep the following packages at their current version:
>   1)      libcgmanager0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   2)      libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 [Not Installed]
>   3)      libglu1-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]
>   4)      libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   5)      libgphoto2-port10:i386 [Not Installed]
>   6)      liblcms2-2:i386 [Not Installed]
>   7)      libsane:i386 [Not Installed]
>   8)      libudev1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   9)      libusb-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   10)     wine [Not Installed]
>   11)     wine1.6 [Not Installed]
>   12)     wine1.6-amd64 [Not Installed]
>   13)     wine1.6-i386:i386 [Not Installed]
>         Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
>   14)     winetricks recommends wine
>
> Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
>
> No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
>   0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

Comment: which broken dependencies do you get. Make your question more informative

Comment: Added som info...

Comment: you can use aptitude to install it. It'll give you some options to resolve dependencies(Caution:Some of the alternatives may include removing or downgrading some packages that you already have). You can reject an alternative by pressing n or if you find any alternatives that you like, you can accept it by pressing Y.

Comment: use `sudo aptitude install wine`

Comment: Just so you know, `sudo apt-get update  && upgrade  & dist-upgrade` doesn't work like you think it does. It runs `apt-get`, then it runs `upgrade`, which isn't a real program.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to add support to i386 architecture, to get it working.

Try running:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: Unfortunately no difference after this.

Answer (score 0):

Wine cannot be installed straight from sudo apt-get install like most other apps. It requires external repositories (an incredibly convoluted and counter productive way of doing things... but ok... you can avoid it installing Wine manually like I will describe below...)

Installing older/different versions of Wine than the latest ones from the repositories in Debian/Ubuntu system is a pain in the rear extremity.

Plan B: consider hopping over to Manjaro, if it's possible for you to do so. Why? Because the Manjaro version of the Wine package comes bundled IN A SINGLE PACKAGE, and you install it using A SINGLE COMMAND:

```
sudo pacman -U /local_path/wine-staging-5.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
or, in the case you miss dependencies..
sudo pacman -Sy /path/wine...
(I think that's the command... I'm not in Manjaro right now,
the Sy command will download the dependencies for you 
WITHOUT performing a full system upgrade, only the packages you need...
pacman -U is the equivalent of sudo dpkg -i , for manual install)
```

OK. If hopping over to Arch/Manjaro is NOT a possibility for you, these below are the steps for MANUALLY installing older versions of Wine on Debian/Ubuntu-based distros:

1. Let's say you want to install Wine version 4.1 (one of the last versions of Wine before the Wineprefix size increased from 100 MB straight to 600 MB, without no additional benefits and no avoidance of the usual bugs from the last 10 years...)
   Go to https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/
   and download all packages that have 4.1 in their name (they should have the same Date to them)

In the case of Wine 4.1 (the version that I've found to be the optimal one) these are the packages you need. You always will need FIVE packages in total.

```
winehq-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging_4.1_buster_i386.deb
wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging-i386_4.1_buster_i386.deb
```

2. Installation order. Here comes the tricky part, after you do it the 1st time it should be easier the next times. First, you install the biggest i386 package, always. Then, you install the small i386 package. Then, install the big amd64 package, and the small amd64 package. The last to be installed should be winehq (which only comes in amd64 form)

Below is a copy of my bash history with the order of commands I used to do this in shortest time.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-i386_4.1_buster_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging_4.1_buster_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/winehq-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
...
winecfg    <used to create the initial Wine prefix>
<use these ones below to reassure that you have all libs installed correctly>
...
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 WINEARCH=win32 winecfg  <to test if 32-bit is working OK>
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 WINEARCH=win64 winecfg  <to test if 64-bit is working OK>
<you should not see errors in the terminal of the type
"but the wrong architecture is being used" >
```

Notice how you need to run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

every single time each package is installed. That will guarantee that the individual dependencies to each package are installed and configured, before you install the next package. (this is only needed the 1st time you do this... after that, you can put all these dependencies, store them in a Backup location, and install them all-at-once using sudo dpkg -i /path/*.deb )

3. Sometimes, and I don't understand why this happens, you won't be able to use Wine 64 bits, or you won't be able to use Wine 32 bits, one of the two. If that happens, simply re-install one of the big Wine packages again (depending if you need amd64 or i386)

   sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb

It's very unfortunate that Wine has been distributed like this on Debian/Ubuntu system, it's an overcomplicated process with a lot of time wasted. The way Manjaro does it should become the official way Wine is distributed from now on.